# Sharing bytearray between processes with multiprocessing manager

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to share a bytearray type variable between processes. However, I couldn't see that there is bytearray type in the `multiprocessing.manager` class. What are the other options to share bytearray variable between processes? I know that I can convert it to string and pass it to `Manager.value("","")` but it is not an efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not looked into `bytearray` specifically, so maybe there's another, more efficient approach to this, but to create a managed object of ANY datatype you want, as long as it's attributes are all picklable, you can follow this sample (just substitute `bytearray` with the class who's object you want to create a manager for):

```
from multiprocessing.managers import NamespaceProxy, BaseManager
import inspect


class ObjProxy(NamespaceProxy):
    """Returns a proxy instance for any user defined data-type. The proxy instance will have the namespace and
    functions of the data-type (except private/protected callables/attributes). Furthermore, the proxy will be
    pickable and can its state can be shared among different processes. """

    @classmethod
    def populate_obj_attributes(cls, real_cls):
        DISALLOWED = set(dir(cls))
        ALLOWED = ['__sizeof__', '__eq__', '__ne__', '__le__', '__repr__', '__dict__', '__lt__',
                   '__gt__']
        DISALLOWED.add('__class__')
        new_dict = {}
        for (attr, value) in inspect.getmembers(real_cls, callable):
            if attr not in DISALLOWED or attr in ALLOWED:
                new_dict[attr] = cls._proxy_wrap(attr)
        return new_dict

    @staticmethod
    def _proxy_wrap(attr):
        """ This method creates function that calls the proxified object's method."""

        def f(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return self._callmethod(attr, args, kwargs)

        return f

attributes = ObjProxy.populate_obj_attributes(bytearray)
bytearrayProxy = type("bytearrayProxy", (ObjProxy,), attributes)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    BaseManager.register('bytearray', bytearray, bytearrayProxy, exposed=tuple(dir(bytearrayProxy)))
    manager = BaseManager()
    manager.start()


    a = [2, 3, 4, 5, 7]
    obj = manager.bytearray(a)
    print(obj)
```

**Output**

```
bytearray(b'\x02\x03\x04\x05\x07')
```

It creates a near perfect proxy for the object of the datatype of you want (in this case it is `bytearray`) by copying all public attributes and methods, including the special dunder methods if the class uses any. You can now pass `obj` to any other process, and the data stored inside this object will be synchronized across all processes.

If you want more details as to how this proxy works, I wrote a detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72817277/16310741)